# Client to debug SQL stored procedure in Mac

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I recently switched to Mac from Windows. I've started with Azure Data studio and VSCode. Is there a way to debug MS SQL stored procedure in Azure Data Studio? When I say debugging, I expect being able to put a break point and execute statements step by step. I'm looking for a client in Mac(preferably Azure Data studio) that could help me debug the stored procedures.
I'm connecting to a docker based SQL Server

Comment: Unfortunately I think Microsoft took a small step in the wrong direction by removing the "step into debugger" from SQL Server Management Studio, so I don't think you'll easily find something. I generally run the code of the procedure sequentially in blocks to debug it, but I agree having an actual debugger would be nice. I'm interested in any answers you may get for this question though.